# How can I perform a long click when using an external keyboard to navigate an Android application?

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibility, contextmenu, onlongclicklistener

I am implementing accessibility in my app, including keyboard navigation. Currently, there is some selectable text which shows the context menu when the user long clicks/long presses the text.

When using an external keyboard to navigate, there is no way to open this context menu that I've found.

I want to show the context menu when the TextView is focused and the Enter or Space key is pressed. This is what I have been trying:

```
textView.setOnKeyListener { view, keyCode, event ->
    if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            performLongClick()
            true
        } else {
            super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
        }
    } else {
        super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

I've also tried the onKeyListener with `view.performContextClick()` and `view.showContextMenu()`, but none of these produce the context menu.

The only thing that has worked for me is creating a custom context menu, and then calling it using the above code.

```
    override fun onCreateContextMenu(
        menu: ContextMenu,
        view: View,
        menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?
    ) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo)
        // add menu items
        menu.add(0, view.id, 0, "Copy")
        menu.add(0, view.id, 0, "Share")
    }

    override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when {
            item.title === "Copy" -> {
                clip = ClipData.newPlainText("copy", text)
                clipBoard?.setPrimaryClip(clip)
            }
            item.title === "Share" -> {
                val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                sharingIntent.type = "text/plain"
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"))
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Ideally I would prefer to show the default context menu. Is there any way to show the context menu using the keyboard without manually creating a context menu?

Comment: Did you also find a solution for mouse users? (:

Comment: And I’m wondering: Isn’t the TextView able to offer these options (longtap etc. to copy, share…) out of the box?